# increase performance func<T> for reflection

Tags: .net-core, automapper

I am currently working on a piece of code that determines the `Type` and the `Value` of a field (all `enum`'s) so we can lookup a translation for the specific enum. I know this is a quite expensive, but i don't see a better solution. Who knows a better fit?

I am using automapper for mapping..

```
//removed some code
CreateMap<CarModel, CarDTO>
    .ForMember(dst => dst.CarBodyType, opt => opt.MapFrom((detail, dto, _, context) => ResolveEnumTranslation(detail, context, car => car.CarBodyType)))
    .ForMember(dst => dst.FuelType, opt => opt.MapFrom((detail, dto, _, context) => ResolveEnumTranslation(detail, context, car => car.FuelType)))
    .ForMember(dst => dst.GearType, opt => opt.MapFrom((detail, dto, _, context) => ResolveEnumTranslation(detail, context, car => car.GearType)))
//removed more for clearity (there are more enums)

private string ResolveEnumTranslation(CarDetail carDetail, ResolutionContext context, Func<CarDetail, object> property)
{
    var selectedEnum = property.Invoke(carDetail);

    if (context.Items.TryGetValue(localeKey, out var locale) && locale is string localeString)
    {
        return carDetail.Country.Translations
            .FirstOrDefault(t => t.EnumType == selectedEnum.GetType().Name
                        && t.EnumValue == (int)selectedEnum
                        && string.Equals(t.CountryLocale?.Locale, localeString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            ?.TranslatedValue ?? property.Invoke(carDetail).ToString();
    }

    return selectedEnum.ToString();
}
```

really curious what would be a better approach.

Comment: Son, what is actually slow about this? Have you profiled it?

Comment: A IMemberResolver will receive the source member to map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the method generic on the `enum` type, which allows to pass in the `enum` value as-is.

This enables to retrieve the `enum` type via `typeof(T)` which occurs at compile time, whereas `selectedEnum.GetType()` occurs at runtime.

You'll have to profile whether this improves performance.

Starting from `C# 7.3` you can even use the generic `Enum` constraint to guard that an `enum` value gets passed as argument; eg.
`where T : Enum`

Call the method below via

```
ResolveEnumTranslation(detail, context, car.GearType)
```

---

```
private string ResolveEnumTranslation<T>(
     CarDetail carDetail, ResolutionContext context, T selectedEnum
     ) where T : Enum
{
    var typeName = typeof(T).Name;

    if (context.Items.TryGetValue(localeKey, out var locale) && locale is string localeString)
    {
        return carDetail.Country.Translations
            .FirstOrDefault(t =>
                 t.EnumType == typeName
                 && t.EnumValue == Convert.ToInt32(selectedEnum)
                 && string.Equals(t.CountryLocale?.Locale, localeString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            )?.TranslatedValue ?? selectedEnum.ToString();
    }

    return selectedEnum.ToString();
}
```

Comment: like this better then my own answer. thnx! i will try to do some profiling to see which is actually faster.